# How should I specify the language in a CMake project that optionally supports CUDA?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I am adding optional CUDA functionalities to a CMake project. Right now, the project is organized as an executable and some static libraries. In the top level `CMakeLists.txt` file there is a `project` statement like this:

```
project (my_project LANGUAGES CXX)
```

And below there an `option` statement adds the parameter to regulate whether to build with the CUDA functionalities or not

```
option(CUDA_FEATS "Set to On to use CUDA features" ON)
```

I am not sure what the correct thing to do would be. Should I:

- Edit the top `project` statement to add CUDA
- Add, after the `CUDA_FEATS` option is set, a statement like `project (my_project LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)` (could this conflict with the initial one?)
- Only put the `project` statement after the parameter has been set

Or something else entirely? What is the best practice in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`enable_language`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html) command, it's pretty self-explanatory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(my_project)

option(CUDA_FEATS "Set to On to use CUDA features" ON)
if (CUDA_FEATS)
    enable_language(CUDA)
endif ()
```

After that point, if `CUDA_FEATS` is true, then you certainly have enabled the CUDA language, have found a compiler, etc.

---

To address your partial solutions:

> Should I:
>
> - Edit the top project statement to add CUDA

No, because you don't *require* CUDA. This is the right thing to do if your project will not build without a CUDA compiler, but when it's optional you should not search for a CUDA compiler you might not use (especially since this will fatal-error if it can't find it!).

> - Add, after the CUDA_FEATS option is set, a statement like project (my_project LANGUAGES CXX CUDA) (could this conflict with the initial one?)

I think this would technically work, just because `project` happens to call `enable_language` internally, but it's very smelly.

> - Only put the project statement after the parameter has been set

The policy settings and project/language detection features are *so essential*, they they should always be configured at the start of your top-level CMakeLists.txt. That means the first two lines ought to be `cmake_minimum_required` and `project`, with no code in between or before. I can't think of any instance when violating this rule would be a hard requirement in modern CMake.